# How to define the type of object's key using same object's another key in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, types, zod

Consider following pseudo type signature for TypeScript:

```
import { z, ZodObject, ZodRawShape } from 'zod';

export type DefinitionObject<T extends ZodRawShape> = {
  validator: ZodObject<T>;
  htmlFn: (value: z.infer<typeof validator> & { locale?: string; }) => JSX.Element;
};
```

The type of `htmlFn` key depends on type of `validator` key via `typeof validator`. But of course, TypeScript errors with:

```
Cannot find name 'validator'.ts (2304)
Parameter 'value' of exported function has or is using private name 'validator'.ts (4078)
```

So, I need something like `this.validator` inside the type signature context. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why not just `z.infer<ZodObject<T>>` ?

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Why did I not think of that before? I was making it unnecessarily complex. The suggestion works! But on a side note, is what I asked possible?

Comment: `z.infer<DefinitionObject<T>['validator']>` could work .. depends what you ware trying to do